# window.getSelection().toString() not working on IE 11

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I have an input field. I want to restrict the users to enter max ten characters. The below code is working on Chrome but not in IE 11. I want when someone highlights the text, they should be able to replace it. In IE11, when I'm highlighting a text, I'm unable to replace it, Possibly the getSelection().toString() is not working.

```js
$('#demo').on('keydown', function(event) {
  var selection = window.getSelection().toString();
  alert(selection);
  var value1 = document.getElementById("demo").value;
  if (value1.length === 10 - selection && event.keyCode != 8) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input contenteditable="true" value="mm/dd/yyyy" id="demo" style="border:none;width:80px;" />
```

Comment: Thanks, I can see it is supported. But I'm unable to change the highlighted text on IE 11. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: I found the solution. Thanks. Please see below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$("#demo").keydown(function(event) {
  var value = this.value;
  // var sel = window.getSelection().toString();
  var sel = value.substring(this.selectionStart, this.selectionEnd);
  if (value.length === 10 - sel && event.keyCode != 8) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input contenteditable="true" value="mm/dd/yyyy" id="demo" style="border:none;width:80px;" />
```

Comment: Yes. I've changed it.

Comment: Converted to a run-able snippet and used 'this' - but not really sure what the 2nd part with the testing is doing / relates to the question - can you tidy up so that it's a clear/clean answer to the question?  Possibly add some text as well.  Answering your own question is fine, but it needs to be an "answer" not just a code snippet.